# Why doesn't conservation of energy hold here while conservation of momentum does?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

[image]

When trying this problem, I first used conservation of energy as follows:
$$\frac{\beta}{4D^2}+\frac{1}{2}m{v_0}^2=\frac{1}{2}m*\frac{4}{9}{v_0}^2+\frac{\beta}{x^2}$$
$$\frac{\beta}{4D^2}=\frac{1}{2}m{v_B}^2+\frac{\beta}{x^2}$$

where $x$ is the final distance between the particles.

Solving by subtracting both equations gives $\boxed{v_B=\frac{i\sqrt{5}}{3}v_0}$, which is clearly wrong.

Alternatively, using the law of conservation of momentum:
$$-mv_0+0=mv_B+m*-\frac{2}{3}v_0$$
Solving gives $\boxed{v_B=-\frac{1}{3}v_0}$ which is the correct answer and also gives the correct direction.

As far as I know, there shouldn't be net work on the system done by an external force which is why conservation of momentum holds, and also why my conservation of energy equations should hold as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both particles can move and the entire system has just one total energy, so you get one equation expressing energy conservation, not two equations, but with two unknowns (the position and speed of B). The momentum method is easier.

Comment: Ah so is it that each particle doesn't have an individual potential energy of $\frac{\beta}{r^2}$ but instead both combined have that potential energy?

Comment: Correct, there is only one potential shared between both particles